# How to change the finder services submenu threshold?

Tags: finder, services, shortcut-menu

In the finder context menu, there is a list of services at the very bottom. Once this list grows beyond 4, it becomes a submenu instead.

Is there a way to affect this threshold, i. e. have five services showing on the first menu level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Terminal, paste the following line and hit return:

```
defaults write -g NSServicesMinimumItemCountForContextSubmenu -int 99; killall Finder
```

You can change 99 to whatever number you prefer – when there are 99 items or more, Finder will place them in a submenu instead of appending them to the context menu. The default is 5.